# flash player update in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates, xubuntu, flash

I have an old laptop which hard disk just works with Xubuntu. Unfortunately, time has passed and Flashplayer needs an update. In many websites I usually visit, I need to update to Adobe Flash Player 11.1. I've been trying to find info to do it from the terminal, but I don't knot why it doesn't work. 
How can I do it?

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) should apply to Xubuntu as well.